# Get id of insertion in prepared query state?

Tags: php

I have some PHP code that inserts alot of stuff into some tables.

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64));
$what = 'profilepicture';
$name = 'Profile picture';
$specs = '';
$add = '';

$insertion = $mysql->prepare("UPDATE users SET image = ? WHERE id = ?");
$insertion->bind_param('ss', $intheendtheimageuknowamk, $myid);

$add_photo_gallery = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users_photos_galleries (uid,name,specs,timestamp,token) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$add_photo_gallery->bind_param('sssss', $myid, 'Profile images', '', $posted_on, $token);
$add_photo_gallery->execute();

$lastid_gallery = $add_photo_gallery->insert_id;
$add_photo = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users_photos (uid,gid,path,name,specs,what,timestamp,token) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$add_photo->bind_param('ssssssss', $myid, $lastid_gallery, $intheendtheimageuknowamk, $name, $specs, $what, $posted_on, $token);
$add_photo->execute();

$lastid_photo = $add_photo->insert_id;
$add_log = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO users_logs (uid,what,relid,addition,timestamp,token) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$add_log->bind_param('ssssss', $myid, $what, $lastid_photo, $add, $posted_on, $token);
$add_log->execute();

echo $intheendtheimageuknowamk;
```

That seems to work by now but some mistakes could occur like if just the second query fails to insert then the rest won't be inserted as well, BUT the first one. I've tried to put every query into an if statement and just talk to the next query if the execution of the previous one was successful but logically that would be the same result. Is there any different way to solve this? Just echo out the ending name by checking all querie's execution wouldn't work either since I need the last_insert ID of the queries which actually is the biggest problem to me tho.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `rowCount()` Method. This method will return how many rows are effekted by your query.

To geht the latest inserted Id use `$id = $mysql->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Yes yes yes I know. That's what I am already doing tho. But I want to check if all queries were fired of successfully and when not, don't insert anything to any table.

Comment: @AyumiTakanashi Use SQL transactions for that.

Comment: Gonna check that out @David

Comment: Dmn David, you saved my day! Thank you alot tho. Even through that I've gotten some very useful knowledge.